# Not sure why I'm getting an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, .net, trygetvalue

I am getting an `InvalidCastException` and I don't understand why.

Here is the code that raises the exception:

```
public static void AddToTriedList(string recipeID)
{
    IList<string> triedIDList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (!settings.Contains("TriedIDList"))
        {
            settings.Add("TriedIDList", new ObservableCollection<Recipe>());
            settings.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            settings.TryGetValue<IList<string>>("TriedIDList", out triedIDList);
        }
        triedIDList.Add(recipeID);
        settings["TriedIDList"] = triedIDList;
        settings.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings in AddToTriedList:");
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

**AppSettings.cs:** (extract)

```
// The isolated storage key names of our settings
const string TriedIDList_KeyName = "TriedIDList";

// The default value of our settings
IList<string> TriedIDList_Default = new ObservableCollection<string>();

...

/// <summary>
/// Property to get and set the TriedList Key.
/// </summary>
public IList<string> TriedIDList
{
    get
    {
        return GetValueOrDefault<IList<string>>(TriedIDList_KeyName, TriedIDList_Default);
    }
    set
    {
        if (AddOrUpdateValue(TriedIDList_KeyName, value))
        {
            Save();
        }
    }
}
```

`GetValueOrDefault<IList<string>>(TriedIDList_KeyName, TriedIDList_Default)` and `AddOrUpdateValue(TriedIDList_KeyName, value)` are the usual methods recommended by Microsoft; you can find the full code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

EDIT: I got exception in this line:

```
settings.TryGetValue<IList<string>>("TriedIDList", out triedIDList);
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception?  Which line?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you stepped through the debugger to identify the specific line that's generating the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forget to write. The exception raises here: settings.TryGetValue<IList<string>>("TriedIDList", out triedIDList);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a `ObservableCollection<Recipe>` to your `settings`:

```
settings.Add("TriedIDList", new ObservableCollection<Recipe>());
                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But then you're reading back a `IList<string>`, which is quite obviously a different type:

```
settings.TryGetValue<IList<string>>("TriedIDList", out triedIDList);
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your declaration of `triedIDList` looks like this:

```
   IList<string> triedIDList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As a start, decide on one type and then use the exact same type in all these places (even if you think it's not strictly necessary), then see if the `InvalidCastException` goes away.

Comment: I would further suggest that you set up a small sandbox project and run a few experiments of your own to see which kinds of conversions are allowed with generic types (and perhaps arrays, too!), and which are not. That's always useful knowledge! ;)

Comment: I'll do, thank you for the suggestion! And thank you again for having solved my exception issue!